# dartdoc: How to split libraries list into subcategories (like in https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/index.html)

Tags: dart, dartdoc

**dartdoc**: How to split libraries list into subcategories (like in https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/index.html)

What I found so far:
the description of subcategories wroten in file https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/sdk/lib/libraries.yaml which is converted to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/sdk/lib/libraries.json by this script https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/tools/yaml2json.dart

where is also several issues about this file, like this:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28836

**But how to tell dartdoc to use this file?**

or how to use subcategories in dartdoc, because I didn't find the way to use them.

**Example** of splitted libraries from https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/index.html
[image]